# Trying to display info from a sql database into an html table

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring

i am having issue with displaying some of the info in my SQL database to a Spring framework HTML table. I am consistently getting an error about looking for an item in the Database that is there, but it can't seem to find it or see it. 
This is the Error:

```
2016-12-01 13:40:13.340  WARN 7968 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42122, SQLState: 42S22
2016-12-01 13:40:13.340 ERROR 7968 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column "LISTITEM0_.SHOPPING_LIST_ID" not found; SQL statement:
select listitem0_.id as id1_0_, listitem0_.contents as contents2_0_, listitem0_.created_utc as created_3_0_, listitem0_.is_checked as is_check4_0_, listitem0_.modified_utc as modified5_0_, listitem0_.priority as priority6_0_, listitem0_.shopping_list_id as shopping7_0_ from list_items listitem0_ [42122-192]
2016-12-01 13:40:13.374 ERROR 7968 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select listitem0_.id as id1_0_, listitem0_.contents as contents2_0_, listitem0_.created_utc as created_3_0_, listitem0_.is_checked as is_check4_0_, listitem0_.modified_utc as modified5_0_, listitem0_.priority as priority6_0_, listitem0_.shopping_list_id as shopping7_0_ from list_items listitem0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "LISTITEM0_.SHOPPING_LIST_ID" not found; SQL statement:
select listitem0_.id as id1_0_, listitem0_.contents as contents2_0_, listitem0_.created_utc as created_3_0_, listitem0_.is_checked as is_check4_0_, listitem0_.modified_utc as modified5_0_, listitem0_.priority as priority6_0_, listitem0_.shopping_list_id as shopping7_0_ from list_items listitem0_ [42122-192]
```

My HTML doc is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="layouts/basic">
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body layout:fragment="content">
    <h1>Shopping List items</h1>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                    <th>Options</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="listitem : ${list_items}">
                    <td th:text="${listitem.contents}"></td>
                    <td><form method="POST" ><input type="hidden" name="listId" th:value="${}"/><button type="submit">Delete</button></form></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    <a href="/">Back</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is also my Data.sql

```
insert into shoppinglist.lists (user_id, name, color, created_utc, modified_utc) values (1, 'Test List', '#000000', '2016-11-30 03:42:56', '2016-11-30 03:42:56');
insert into shoppinglist.lists (user_id, name, color, created_utc, modified_utc) values (2, 'Test List 2', '#000000', '2016-11-30 03:42:56', '2016-11-30 03:42:56');
insert into shoppinglist.lists (user_id, name, color, created_utc, modified_utc) values (3, 'Test List 3', '#000000', '2016-11-30 03:42:56', '2016-11-30 03:42:56');
insert into shoppinglist.lists (user_id, name, color, created_utc, modified_utc) values (4, 'Test List 4', '#000000', '2016-11-30 03:42:56', '2016-11-30 03:42:56');

insert into shoppinglist.list_items (list_id, contents, priority, is_checked, created_utc, modified_utc) values (1, 'Hello there', 1, false, '2016-11-30 03:42:56', '2016-11-30 03:42:56');
insert into shoppinglist.list_items (list_id, contents, priority, is_checked, created_utc, modified_utc) values (2, 'Hello there', 1, false, '2016-11-30 03:42:56', '2016-11-30 03:42:56');
insert into shoppinglist.list_items (list_id, contents, priority, is_checked, created_utc, modified_utc) values (3, 'Hello there', 1, false, '2016-11-30 03:42:56', '2016-11-30 03:42:56');
insert into shoppinglist.list_items (list_id, contents, priority, is_checked, created_utc, modified_utc) values (4, 'Hello there', 1, false, '2016-11-30 03:42:56', '2016-11-30 03:42:56');

insert into shoppinglist.notes (item_id, body, created_utc, modified_utc) values ('1', 'this is where my paragraph would go', '2016-11-30 03:42:56', '2016-11-30 03:42:56');
```

and lastly my controller

```
@Controller
public class ListController {

    @Autowired
    private ListRepository listRepo;
    @Autowired
    private ListItemRepository listItemRepo;

    @GetMapping("")
    public String index(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/ListsofLists")
    public String List(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("lists", listRepo.findAll());
        return "list_of_lists";
    }

    @GetMapping("/ListsofLists/{id}")
    public String listitems(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
        model.addAttribute("id", id);
        // never forget to import the proper beans!
        ListItem u = listItemRepo.findOne(id);

        model.addAttribute("list_items", u);
        // yes I am going with listing the lists, I thought it would be funny.
        return "list_list";
    }

    // GetMapping and PostMapping for editing items in lists.
    @GetMapping("/ListsofLists/{id}/edit")
    public String listEdit(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
        model.addAttribute("id", id);
        List u = listRepo.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("lists", u);
        return "list_edit";
    }

    @PostMapping("/ListsofLists/{userId}/edit")
    public String listEditSave(@ModelAttribute @Valid List list, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        listRepo.save(list);
        return "redirect:/ListsofLists/" + list.getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My partner had found the error. we had a Variable in one of our beans be off after a series of refactoring earlier today.